# Select em duas tabelas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

```
Ban.cs
public partial class Ban
    {
        public int IdBan { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DataBan { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DataDesban { get; set; }
        public int Usuario_IdUsuario { get; set; }
        public string Motivo { get; set; }

        public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
    }


Usuario.cs
public partial class Usuario
    {
        public Usuario()
        {
            this.Avaliacao = new HashSet<Avaliacao>();
            this.Ban = new HashSet<Ban>();
            this.Comentario = new HashSet<Comentario>();
            this.Denuncia = new HashSet<Denuncia>();
            this.Login = new HashSet<Login>();
            this.Mensagens = new HashSet<Mensagens>();
            this.Mensagens1 = new HashSet<Mensagens>();
            this.Pedido = new HashSet<Pedido>();
            this.Publicacao = new HashSet<Publicacao>();
            this.UsuarioPermissoes = new HashSet<UsuarioPermissoes>();
        }

        public int IdUsuario { get; set; }
        public string NomeCompleto { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Senha { get; set; }
        public string Sexo { get; set; }
        public string Telefone { get; set; }
        public string About { get; set; }
        public string Nickname { get; set; }
        public string Email2 { get; set; }
        public string Endereco { get; set; }
        public string Bairro { get; set; }
        public string Estado { get; set; }
        public string Cep { get; set; }
        public string Celular { get; set; }
        public string FotoPerfil { get; set; }
        public string StatusPerfil { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> NBans { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Banido { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DtCadastro { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DtNasc { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Avaliacao> Avaliacao { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Ban> Ban { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Comentario> Comentario { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Denuncia> Denuncia { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Login> Login { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Mensagens> Mensagens { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Mensagens> Mensagens1 { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Pedido> Pedido { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Publicacao> Publicacao { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UsuarioPermissoes> UsuarioPermissoes { get; set; }
    }
```

Eu tenho uma action que retorna uma lista de bans do site. Porém, eu não quero retornar apenas os dados dessa tabela "Ban", eu gostaria de exibir também o nome do Usuário que foi banido, para facilitar a identificação dos usuarios que foram banidos.
Como eu faço para exbir o nome do usuário junto com os dados da tabela "Ban"?

Comment: Você pode colocar na sua pergunta como estão os models de Ban e Usuário?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Em questão de relacionamento? Ou você quer ver o código das duas classes?

Comment: O código dos dois Models.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Atualizei. As classes foram criadas automaticamente pelo EF. Há algum problema?

Comment: Não, de forma alguma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem segredo:

```
var ban = contexto.Bans.Include(b => b.Usuario).FirstOrDefault();
var nomeUsuario = ban.Usuario.Nome;
```

Comment: Realmente! Muito obrigado.